# Shortest path with depth first search

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

How can I get the shortest path using DFS.  I've seen this question asked several times, but the replies are generally use BFS or a different algorithm.  What about in the context of a robot traversing a maze?  BFS isn't possible since it jumps from node to node and a robot would require backtracking.

Right now I am trying to solve the problem using:

```
def dfs(self, v):
    v.visited = True
    for adj in v.adj:
        if adj.visited is False:
            # set the parent
            adj.successor = v
            # explore the other nodes
            self.dfs(adj)
```

However, this does not necessarily return the shortest path.  Is there another way to approach this problem? I've seen some suggestions to use depth first iterative deepening, but I can't find many examples implementing this algorithm.

Comment: I think the idea behind depth first search iterative deepening is that you can write a depth first search that doesn't pursue the recursion if it is trying to go deeper than N. If you run it with N=1, N=2, N=3... the first time it succeeds in finding the destination it has found it with a path of length N and it knows there is no path of length < N that works, so the path of length N must be the shortest path.

Comment: There's also the ***[ant colony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms)***

Comment: I find it _very_ hard to believe that any serious searching was done. DFS is covered extensively on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume) and in pretty much any algorithm programming resource.

Comment: Jordi, I fail to see what a polyhedron has to do with DFS. Additionally while it is covered heavily, it doesn't elobate on how to modify it to get the shortest path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in how I solved this here is my solution:

```
def dfs(self, v):
    if v.successor is None:  # this is the root node
        v.cost = 0
    v.visited = True
    for adj in v.adj:
        if adj.visited is False:
            # set the parent
            adj.successor = v
            adj.cost = v.cost + 1
            self.dfs(adj)
        # if the cost is less switch the successor
        # and set the new cost
        elif adj.cost > v.cost + 1:
            adj.successor = v
            adj.cost = v.cost + 1
            self.dfs(adj)
```

This is essentially a version of DFS that keeps track of the cost for each vertex.  If the cost of the vertex is more than a successor + 1 step then it sets the new successor.  This allows for finding the shortest path without using BFS.